# docker compose asyncio.sleep block statements before

Tags: python, docker-compose, python-asyncio

I've been beating myself to solve this problem that seems very weird. Consider this python code:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print("hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("world")

asyncio.run(main())
```

I'd like to run this as a docker compose service, so here's my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./main.py /app

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

and docker-compose.yaml is simply:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services: 
  dnsgen:
    build: ./dnsgen
```

Now here's the issue if I run `docker compose up dnsgen --build --timestamps` the prints happen simultaneously after waiting 10 seconds:

```
dnsgen-1  | 2024-02-04T01:16:25.341721172+01:00hello
dnsgen-1  | 2024-02-04T01:16:25.341784837+01:00world
```

This doesn't happen of course if I run `python main.py` on my machine or even when I run `docker compose run dnsgen`. I invite you to try this out and see if this problem persists, and please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.

I suspect that this is simply a buffering issue: printed output doesn't show up in the logs until (a) the output buffer is full or (b) the program exits. The timestamps you see don't have anything to do with when the print statement was executed; they represent when the output was delivered to the output logging mechanism.

You can verify this by using unbuffered output -- either by printing to *stderr* instead of *stdout* (*stderr* is unbuffered by default), or by running Python with the `-u` option. E.g., if we write the `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./main.py /app

CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

Then we see:

```
Attaching to dnsgen-1
dnsgen-1  | 2024-02-03T19:48:07.972264989-05:00hello
dnsgen-1  | 2024-02-03T19:48:17.985659019-05:00world
dnsgen-1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Why isn't this the default behaviour?

Comment: This is not the default behavior because buffered output requires fewer cpu and io resources (because we're only writing out data when we have a large chunk of it, rather than writing out every single character individually).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variable or starting with parameter is equivalent

- [PYTHONUNBUFFERED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)
- ["python -u"](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Debian 12 & Python 3.12
FROM python:3.12-slim-bookworm

# Internal signal that should be sent inside the image, if you stop the docker deamon
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
# Python output is sent straight to terminal/logs without being first buffered
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./main.py /app

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```